# Split the string and pass each element as argument in perl

Tags: perl

I want to pass the hash key and pair values as argument to function. The below code I have tried. Please advise the way we can pass arguments to function by split the string or mapping the hash.

```
use strict;
my %hash=(1=>"Hi",2=>"Hello");

func(map { "$_,$hash{$_}" } keys %hash);

sub func{
#Statements will go here
my $arg1=shift;
my $arg2=shift;
my $arg3=shift;
my $arg4=shift;
print "$arg1,$arg2,$arg3,$arg4";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple values from a `map` BLOCK. You could use

```
func(map { $_, $hash{$_} } keys %hash);
```

but that's just the same as

```
func(%hash);
```

This passes the keys and values of the hash, so you could do

```
sub func {
    say join ", ", @_;
}
```

But to lookup values by keys means reconstructing the hash.

```
sub func {
    my %new_hash = @_;
    say $new_hash{2};
}

func(%hash);
```

It's rather ridiculous to pass the elements of the hash to create a new hash on the inside. So let's pass the hash instead. This can't actually be done, but we could pass a reference to the hash.

```
sub func {
   my ($hash) = @_;
   say $hash->{2};
}

func(\%hash);
```

Comment: I am passing the arguments to one of the function in ARS perl module. In which, I need to pass sufficient amount of arguments. When I pass like what I coded in above is not accepting.

Answer (score 0):

May be a more elegant way but this works :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my %hash=(1=>"Hi",2=>"Hello");
my @list=%hash;

func1(\@list);
func2(\%hash);

sub func1{
        #Statements will go here
        my @args = @{+shift};
        print join(',',@args), "\n";
}

sub func2{
        #Statements will go here
        my %args = %{+shift};
        print join(',',keys %args), "\n";
}
```

Comment: This still ends up needlessly recreating the hash (or array) in the sub. Using a reference is the way to go, but actually use the reference!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes, it should be,

```
func(map { $hash{$_},$_ } keys %hash);
```

When you are using quotes to the string, it is a singe data.

For example,

```
func ("data1,data2,data3"); #Here you are passing single parameter to a function. You are doing this mistake. 

func ("data1","data2","data3"); #Here you are passing three parameters to the function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the hash itself in directly, e.g.

```
func( %hash );
```

The hash key/value pairs are flattened out into the argument array `@_`.

```
sub func
{
    print join ",", @_;
}
```